# native datepicker is grayed out on Iphone 12 Mini (and above versions)

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using native datepicker

and my problem is that the date input field is grayed out on Iphone 12 mini and above versions .

I know it's dependant on the browser and OS but maybe there is some way to fix this issue?
I want to change somehow the appearence
and also I don't want to use custom datepicker . I know that custom datepicker is solution but maybe someone had same problem before .